# Use C# to send SMS via old Nokia phone

Tags: c#, sms, nokia, connectivity

I'm a beginner in developing an application to interact with a Nokia phone. My final goal is to use my old Nokia phone and send a SMS. I've read a lot of documentation online to see how this is done but I'm very confused as where to start. So far, I understand that I need a Nokia phone and connect it to the computer via serial cable. But in order for my C# application to interact with it, do I install PC Connectivity 3.0 or Nokia PC Suite 7.1 for that? Also I'm looking into GSMCOMM library for my C# application, but their documentation starts at the developer has already resolved all PC to Phone connectivity issues. If anybody has experience in development in .NET with Nokia phones, can you provide full steps or tutorials on how I can get started? Thanks!!!

Comment: SO works best when you have a specific problem, rather than a generic "how do I do X"

Comment: I'm sorry, what does SO stand for in this case?

Comment: Stack Overflow, as in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) for this application!

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
//Replace "COM7"withcorresponding port name
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort(post, 115200);


Thread.Sleep(1000);

_serialPort.Open();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");

Thread.Sleep(1000);

_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r\n");

Thread.Sleep(1000);

_serialPort.Write(message + "\x1A");

Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Close();
```